# Agreement with sentences which have negative meaning

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, questions

Which word should be used in this imaginary situation?

> Teacher : I am afraid, all your ten answers are wrong.
>
> Student : Well I was sure for my answer for the question number 10. Even is that one wrong [.......]?

A: too
B: neither

Comment: What would be your own choice, and why?

Comment: You don't want a comma, and your ***all*** is in one of the few positions that are 100% "invalid". You can have *"**all** your ten answers are wrong"*, *"your ten answers are **all** wrong"*, or even (at a pinch, formal/dated phrasing) *"your ten answers **all** are wrong"*, but not your version. Apart from that, I don't understand the question.

Comment: You were sure *of* your answer for question #10. Is it wrong *too*?

Comment: Side note: Should be, "Teacher: I am afraid that all ten of your answers are wrong." Not "your all ten" but "all ten of your". And "I was sure of my answer ..." not "sure for".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off:

> Teacher : I am afraid, your all ten answers are wrong.
>
> Student : Well I was sure for my answer for the question number 10. Even is it wrong .......?

As Fumblefingers pointed out in a comment above, you have several options for positioning the word *all,* but your choice isn't one of them.  Also, having a comma after "afraid" makes it look like the teacher is actually scared of something.  Let's go with:

> Teacher: I am afraid all ten of your answers are wrong.

Student's response needs a little work too.  Usually we say that we are "sure *of*" things, not "sure *for*" things.  Also, *Question #10* doesn't need an article. (It would if we were calling it *"the tenth question,"* or *"the last question"*) Finally, Student's second sentence doesn't really work, but fixing the grammar of it may make your question a moot point, so I will leave it be - for now.:

> Student : Well, I was sure of my answer for question number 10. [ Even is it wrong .......?]

You have a few choices for that second sentence.

1. *Is even that one wrong?*
2. *Is it wrong too?*
3. *Is it wrong also?*

Given the context (Student got all of the questions wrong, but really thought he had a good answer for number 10) I think the first version makes the most sense.  He isn't really asking if it is wrong (teacher has already told him so) but expressing dismay.  Version 2 and 3, with *too* and *also* would make more sense if he didn't yet know whether that last answer was incorrect.

> Teacher: I am afraid that your first nine answers were terrible and you made a small mistake in #10.
> Student: Is it wrong *too/also?*

Choosing to use ***neither*** is not based on whether sentences have a "negative" meaning (wrong, bad, evil).  It is used to negate a sentence - to reverse the meaning - when there are two subjects to the sentence. Your teacher might say *"Neither #2 nor #6 are correct."*  (Both are wrong.)  Or she might say *"Neither #2 nor #6 are incorrect"*  (Both are right.)  One of the subjects may be implied by context.  *"Your answer to #2 was not correct.  Neither was your answer to #6."*

Answer (score 1):

Neither:

```
Teacher : I am afraid all ten of your answers are incorrect.

Student : Well I was sure of my answer for question number 10. Even it is incorrect?
```

Comment: I would be helpful to explain why "Neither" is the correct answer. Why is "incorrect" a better choice than "wrong"? Why can't we say "sure for"? Giving a better wording helps the asker for this one question. Explaining why it is better wording helps them apply your answer to other situations.